# Simile Mark on sheet music

Tags: notation, repeats

On the sheet music I am playing, I have faced 3 **simile** Mark each on different bar continuously. Does it mean I should repeat 3 measures back ?

Comment: An image would make a big difference!

Comment: The tags make no sense (?)…

Comment: Are you asking about the word "simile", or are you asking about the measure repeat sign */*?

Answer (score 2):

The marking **simile** or **sim.** instructs the performer to continue to play something in the same way (in a similar way, I guess is the easiest way to remember this translation from Italian). For instance, a bar or passage of music may have staccato markings over each note; a marking of simile over the following notes would tell you to continue to play staccato. It saves continuing to write performance markings which remain the same.